# How to get the fps of a video from QuickTime Player's inspector using applescript

Tags: applescript, video, quicktime

I need a quick and easy way to find the frame rate of a video in applescript. So far grabbing it through QuickTime Player's inspector seems like the easiest option.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set the_movie to choose file
    open the_movie
    delay 1
    if not (document 1 exists) then return beep 1
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
        if not ((window 1 whose name ends with "Inspector") exists) then
            keystroke "i" using {command down} -- “Show Movie Inspector” menu   command
        end if
        set theInspector to window 1 whose name ends with "Inspector"
        set {X, Y} to position of static text 1 of theInspector whose value is "FPS:"
        set theFrameRate to value of text area 1 of theInspector whose position is {X + 120, Y}
    end tell
end tell

display dialog theFrameRate
```

I found this code on the internet, but it cant seem to locate the inspector's text area. Can anyone help me out? I'm running el capitan